# Is my pressure cooker good for the trash bin?

Tags: pressure-cooker

Some serious meat burning occurred in my cooker, and now some of the material on the surface of the bottom of the cooker is gone:

[image]
[image]

Still usable?

Comment: Is it an aluminum pressure cooker, or a steel one? Did it have a non-stick coating originally?

Comment: The problem I see are the scratches, you should try to smooth these out by doing what @moscafj says in his answer; loads of elbow grease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some scouring powder and/or steel wool and elbow grease.  This is not a health issue, just aesthetic.  Although, it may scorch more easily if you don't clean it well.

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't need to rash this pressure cooker.  This is only discoloration of the top layer of the stainless steel.  Just polish with a stainless steel cleaner, scouring powder, or barkeeper's friend and it will come right off.

Next time make sure you have enough liquid to bring your cooker to pressure, and when browning meat, if it sticks simply add cold water to the hot pressure cooker.  Attack it with a spatula to lift-up any browned or burned bits - then incorporate them in the sauce. : )

Comment: If it is really just discoloration - agreed. If there is actually material gone or if there are deep scratches, I'd be afraid for my life pressurizing that .